# Could not autowire. Qualified bean must be

Tags: java, spring

Делаю подключение к БД.

код с ошибкой

@Qualifier("mainDatasource") - компилятор пишет 
Could not autowire. Qualified bean must be of 'DataSource' type. less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:Checks autowiring problems in a bean class.

```
@Singleton
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
@Configuration

public class DataSourceSingleton {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mainDatasource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

класс который его дергает

```
@Repository
public class KladrRepository {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(KladrRepository.class);
    @Autowired
    private DataSourceSingleton holderData;
    @Resource
    private SpAddCoordinate spAddCoordinate;
    @Resource
    private CoordinateCache coordinateCache;

    private SpGetDataForYandexMap getAccountInfo;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        getAccountInfo = new SpGetDataForYandexMap(holder.getDataSource());
    }


    public Map<Long, Pair<Double, Double>> getIdCoordinates() throws RepositoryException {
        return coordinateCache.
                getIdCoordinates();
    }
}
```

файл конфигурации

```
<bean id="kladrRepository" class="ru.liberty.kladr.yandex.db.KladrRepository" init-method="postConstruct">
    </bean>

    <bean id="kladrDataSourceSingleton" class="ru.liberty.kladr.yandex.db.KladrDataSourceSingleton">
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourceSingleton" class="ru.liberty.kladr.yandex.db.DataSourceSingleton">
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="post.kfins.ru"/>
    </bean>

    <!--DataSources-->
    <bean id="mainDatasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/kfins-front/SybaseDB"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под именем `mainDatasource` у вас объявлен бин, который реализован классом `org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean`. А Вы пытаетесь его заинжектить в поле с типом `DataSource`, на что и получаете ошибку. JndiObjectFactoryBean не имеет во всей своей цепочке наследования класса DataSource.